# Chrome Extension: When I click on context menu item how can i get the clicked input information?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

First I created a context menu item with below code.

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: "addToinputFiller",
    title: "Add to Input Filler",
    contexts: ["editable"]
});
```

Then I added a *onClicked* listener for catching up which input was clicked.

```
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function (info, tab) {
    if (tab) {
         //getting the clicked input id   
    }
});
```

I want to get information about clicked input in the listener. But info and tab parameters can't contain any information about the clicked input. How can i get the clicked input information, especially id, in the listener?

Comment: Use a *content script* and listen to `contextmenu` event.

Comment: I activated _content script_ and moved _onCicked_ event from `backgroud.js` to it. But it couldn't fired.

Comment: Of course it won't work: chrome.contextMenus API is only available in the background page. The `contextmenu` event is a standard DOM event which you can listen to in a content script e.g. window.addEventListener('contextmenu', foo)